# Oracle jet components loading issue in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, oracle-jet

I am working on Oracle jet with Perl. I am facing loading issue with ojet components.
When I load the page first time it is loading the page without any issue, but when I try to reload the page then it is breaking. I am not getting errors but components are not getting rendered. Showing empty space at unloaded components.
 When I check the components in inspect element, it is having this

`[data-bind*="ojComponent"]:not(.oj-component-initnode) {
         visibility: hidden;
        }`

I am facing this issue mainly in chrome browser. Firefox seems good.

EDIT:
   When I open the page in debug mode (inspect element) then it is working fine. 
   What additional things will happen in debug mode? Is there anything that 
   forcing to load all components in debug mode?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: An example and version number would be nice

Comment: I am using ojCombobox, ojSelectbox and version is 2.2.0 . I am not doing any complicated operations. I have 2 select box and loading data into second box based on first box using ajax async call and also using radio buttons and submit button. This is what my page contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my browser has some issue. Same page is working perfectly when I tested on other's system.